# Violación de segmento (`core' generado) usando c++

Tags: c++

En un programa muy sencillo es un método Burbuja el cual solo tiene que ordenar 5 números, pero cuando lo ejecuto solo me muestra "Violación de segmento (`core' generado)" y el programa es este

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( ) {    
  int numero[] = { 4, 1, 2, 3, 5 };
  int i = 0, j = 0, aux = 0;

  cout << "b";

  // Algoritmo del metodo burbuja
  for( i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    for( j = 0; i < 5; ++j ) {
      if( numero[j] > numero[j+1] ) {
        aux = numero[j];
        numero[j] = numero[j+1];
        numero[j+1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }

  // Imprimir la lista
  cout << "Orden Ascendente: ";

  for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    cout << numero[i] << ' ';
  }

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: En el `for( )` interno has puesto otra vez `i < 5`, cuando debería ser `j < 5`.

Comment: Además, si usas el índice *j+1*, entonces *j* puede ser como mucho 3.